# Responsive + fixed width rules not being applied

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have a div that has several "steps" in size:

```
<div class="flex flex-row sm:w-full lg:w-1024 xl:w-1400">
```

My problem is that no matter the screen with, the sm:w-full class is the only one that ever gets applied.

This seems to be a problem with the tailwind-generated css; it has:

```
@media (min-width: 640px) {
  .sm\:w-full {
    width: 100%;
  }
```

...but nothing corresponding in the sections for lg or xl; in fact, lg is only:

```
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .lg\:py-0 {
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
  }
}
```

Other responsive rules are working; e.g. I have a grid:

```
div("grid sm:grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 xl:grid-cols-3 w-screen")
```

...which does the right thing. I can see the grid-cols-2 and grid-cols-3 rules in the md and xl blocks in the generated css.

So, why are these width rules not getting generated?

For completeness, here is my tailwind config:

```
module.exports = {
    darkMode: "class",
    content: [
        "./src/**/*.kt",
        "./build/js/node_modules/flowbite/**/*.js"],
    theme: {
        extend: {
            colors: {
                primary: { "50": "#eff6ff", "100": "#dbeafe", "200": "#bfdbfe", "300": "#93c5fd", "400": "#60a5fa", "500": "#3b82f6", "600": "#2563eb", "700": "#1d4ed8", "800": "#1e40af", "900": "#1e3a8a" }
            },
            fontFamily: {
                'sans': ['Inter', 'ui-sans-serif', 'system-ui', '-apple-system', 'system-ui', 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', 'Noto Sans', 'sans-serif', 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol', 'Noto Color Emoji'],
                'body': ['Inter', 'ui-sans-serif', 'system-ui', '-apple-system', 'system-ui', 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', 'Noto Sans', 'sans-serif', 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol', 'Noto Color Emoji'],
                'mono': ['ui-monospace', 'SFMono-Regular', 'Menlo', 'Monaco', 'Consolas', 'Liberation Mono', 'Courier New', 'monospace']
            },
            minWidth: {
                'kanban': '19rem'
            },
            textDecoration: ['active'],
            transitionProperty: {
                'width': 'width'
            },
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        require('./build/js/node_modules/flowbite/plugin')
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [Tailwind Docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/width#arbitrary-values):

> If you need to use a one-off width value that doesn’t make sense to include in your theme, use square brackets to generate a property on the fly using any arbitrary value.

Do it like this:

```
<div class="flex flex-row sm:w-full lg:w-[1024px] xl:w-[1400px]">
```

Answer (score -1):

I misunderstood the [Tailwind documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/width), which states:

> Fixed widths
> Use w-{number} or w-px to set an element to a fixed width.

I interpreted that to mean *any* number or px value would work, but Tailwind only supports the explicitly listed set of `w-N` constants that they have listed on that page.

In order to use values not listed, such as w-1024, w-1400, etc., it's necessary to add custom widths in the theme in the tailwind config, e.g.:

```
width: {
    '1024': '1024px',
    '1400': '1400px',
},
```

With this in place (and the CSS regenerated) the above div works as intended.